# JavaFX bind a child's property to its parent's property as soon as a new child is added

Tags: java, javafx-8

I hava a `Pane` which is zoomable. I would like to scale all the children in this `Pane` respectively. Children can be added dynamically, so I was thinking of binding the scale property of the child to its parent's scale property once a new child is added but I have no idea how one can do this.

I currently scale all children as soon as the pane is scaled:

```
public class ZoomableCanvas extends Pane {

    DoubleProperty scale = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);

    public ZoomableCanvas() {
        scaleXProperty().bind(scale);
        scaleYProperty().bind(scale);
    }

    public double getScale() {
        return scale.get();
    }

    public void setScale(double scale) {
        this.scale.set(scale);
        for (javafx.scene.Node child : getChildren()) {
            child.setScaleX(scale);
            child.setScaleY(scale);
        }
    }

    public void setPivot(double x, double y) {
        setTranslateX(getTranslateX() - x);
        setTranslateY(getTranslateY() - y);
    }
}
```

But there has to be a more elegant way. How can I listen for the adding of children and then bind the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just observe the children list:

```
public class ZoomableCanvas extends Pane {

    DoubleProperty scale = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);

    public ZoomableCanvas() {
        scaleXProperty().bind(scale);
        scaleYProperty().bind(scale);

        getChildren().addListener((Change<? extends Node> c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    for (Node child : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                        child.scaleXProperty().bind(scale);
                        child.scaleYProperty().bind(scale);
                    }
                }
                if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                    for (Node child : c.getRemoved()) {
                        child.scaleXProperty().unbind();
                        child.scaleYProperty().unbind();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public double getScale() {
        return scale.get();
    }

    public void setScale(double scale) {
        this.scale.set(scale);
    }

    public void setPivot(double x, double y) {
        setTranslateX(getTranslateX() - x);
        setTranslateY(getTranslateY() - y);
    }
}
```